# Same code dont work without selenium (list out of index)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying scrap data of a static website, but my first code had a horrible performance although worked.

**bad code:**

```
lista_teste = ['CRA0160000P','CRA0160000X']
data = []
blank_row = []
final_df = pd.DataFrame()



for cr in lista_teste:
    driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
    driver.get(url_cr.format(cr))
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    try:
        html_data = soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
        for element in html_data:
            sub_data = []
            for sub_element in element:
                try:
                    sub_data.append(sub_element.get_text())
                except:
                    continue
            data.append(sub_data)
            cr_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            cr_df[6] = cr
        final_df = final_df.append(cr_df)
    except:
        continue


final_df.dropna(AXIS = 0, inplace= True)
```

but the fact of the site be static made my selenium be unnecessary, so i wanna try improve my performance using the site without the selenium.

```
data = []
blank_row = []
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in lista_teste:
        site = requests.get('https://data.anbima.com.br/certificado-de-recebiveis/{i}/agenda')
        html = site.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        scrap = soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[1:]
        for element in soup:
            sub_data = []
            for sub_element in element:
                try:
                    sub_data.append(sub_element.get_text())
                except:
                    continue
            data.append(sub_data)
            cr_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            cr_df[6] = i
        final_df = final_df.append(cr_df)
```

The error is on line `scrap = soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[1:]`, where i receive back "IndexError: list of range"

How the list can be out of range working without webdriver, if with work well?

Comment: Looks like the site uses `g-google-authorization header. And it changes for each request. So the best bet is to stick with selenium, unless you can replicate it.

Comment: some tip to improve my code with selenium ? With the list that i really use i'm spending like a hour and half, much more that i consider a good performance.